# Volume integral of pressure interpretation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, work

If you have a fluid with with pressure field $p$ what is the physical significance of the the volume integral of the pressure $\int_V p dV$?

Comment: Can you give some more context about where this quantity shows up? Kyle's answer below covers one interpretation but it is for *changes* in volume between two states. But it could also just be a way to define a mean value...

Comment: $pdV$ shows the elementary work done on the fluid. The term $dV$ represents elementary  change in the volume of the fluid under pressure $P$

Answer (score 2):

The equation for work W that you have written comes from the relationship we learned in freshman physics, $W=\int{Fdx}$.  If A the area over which the force acts, then the pressure is $p=F/A$, and the differential change in volume is dV=Adx.  So,

$$W=\int{Fdx}=\int{\left(\frac{F}{A}\right)Adx}=\int{pdV}$$

In terms of interpretation of the integral as an average, we can define the average pressure as $\bar{p}=W/\Delta V$.  So, the average pressure during the volume change is given by:$$\bar{p}=\frac{\int{pdV}}{\Delta V}$$

Answer (score 0):

The significance is that it is the [work done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_%28thermodynamics%29#Pressure-volume_work) by the fluid.

> Moreover,
>   $$
> W=\int_{V_i}^{V_f} P\,dV
> $$
>   where $W$ denotes the work done by the system during the whole of the reversible process.

This relation appears regularly in thermodynamics, usually as the [first law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics)
$$
dU=\delta Q+\delta W=\delta Q-pdV
$$
(the minus sign represents the work done *on* the system, rather than *by* the system)

Comment: This was what I thought first also -- but that's only for changes in volume right? A volume integral of any quantity in a volume is really just... the average value in the volume times the volume... Perhaps we need more context?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it could be the mean value of the pressure in the domain as well. Guess it would depend on OP's context; hopefully they'll respond to your comment on their post.